# How to increase time out of webform webmethod request in asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, connection-timeout

I am using webform c#, here one of my method is taking about 3-4 minutes to execute completely method runs absolutely fine in developing environment but when publish put it on IIS it produces error of time out. i have tried with both ajax and server side button click event both but got same issue. **I have also tried to increase the connection time out setting from IIS**, it also doesn't work. **on project webconfig I have changed these lines**, not worked.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

Is there any other way or I am missing any thing something? My IIS version is 10

Comment: how did you increase the connection time out setting from IIS? usually we follow this method: 1.Open your IIS 2.Go to "Sites" option 3.Mouse right click 4.Then open property "Manage Web Site" 5.Then click on "Advance Settings" 6.Expand section "Connection Limits", here you can set your "connection time out".

Comment: @samwu yeah that's the way

Comment: can you post your web.config file?

Comment: should i send it on your chat

Comment: You can post it in this thread, but remember to remove your private information.

Answer (score 0):

In Web.config executionTimeout setting in seconds. so as per your details it's taking 3-4 minutes. so you need to set it as per that. like. executionTimeout="600"  (600 sec : 5 minute)

And instead of globally increases the timeout of all pages you can also be applied for specific pages in the following way.

```
<location path="yourpagename.aspx">
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="900"/>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: have done that already, but couldn't get the result on IIS.